# django python encode produce strange output

Tags: python, django, utf-8, encode

i generate a string with html code. These string i insert in a template like this:

```
header = render_to_string('header.html', {'content': header_content})
```

The template looks like this:

```
  ...
  {% autoescape off %}
  {{ content }}
  {% endautoescape %}
  </body>
  ...
```

Now i have a string variable named "header".
I would like to store these string as a html file in my storage (AWS S3).

I try to create a temporary file with django contentfile. For this i must encode the string. It looks like this:

```
self.export_settings.header.save("header.html", ContentFile(header.encode()))
```

Now i have a html file in my s3 storage but sometimes with strange content.
For example i have a table with an empty column.

Before i call `header.encode()` it looks like this (this is a part of the content that i insert in the template, it came from a user that create it with TinyMCE):

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 32.1574%;">Test</td>
<td style="width: 32.237%;"> </td>
<td style="width: 32.237%; text-align: right;">Site <span class="page"> of <span class="topage"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

But after i call `.encode()` and save it to storage, the html file shows this in the second column:
[image]

Why? That is not what i want. I would like to store my string that represents html code as a html file without convert the content to strange characters.
I have read that the utf-8 encoding may the reason for this but how can i do what i want without encode? ContentFile expect bytes, not string.

Comment: If you think you need UTF-8, why are you not passing `'utf-8'` as a parameter to `encode`?

Comment: I don't know if utf-8 is the best for me. But i believe utf-8 is the default for encode.

Comment: You are correct, the default for [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) is `utf-8`.  But it wasn't always so, I don't know when it changed.

Comment: I try it with `header.encode('utf-8')` but it is the same output.

Comment: I have to assume your template has a hidden character that is not showing up in your question.  That makes this question kind of hard to answer.

Comment: Okay but what is the hidden character? You can see the second column in my question (`<td style="width: 32.237%;"> </td>`). Is a whitespace between `>` and `<`... But the content is not in the template, this is the content that i insert in the template via context. These content is generate from a user with TinyMce.

Comment: Did you think that was an unimportant detail to leave out of the question?

Comment: Sorry i have forget this.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by set the encoding to ascii because i have read that ContentFile encode with ascii. Here is the code:

```
ContentFile(header.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
```

Now all worked fine!